# Navigating mobile apps using Appium and Geb

Tags: automation, automated-tests, appium, geb, appium-ios

I'm trying to create a navigation scheme for automating several test suites for my mobile apps using Appium and Geb. I am trying to accomplish this by utilizing primarily the `to()`, `onUnload()` and `onLoad()` methods of the `Page` class. I have defined an individual `Page` for each discrete "page" of my apps. The `to()` methods for each page defines a procedure for navigating to that page and the `onUnload()` and `onLoad()` methods defines any actions that need to be taken in order to allow navigation to or away from those pages which cannot be defined in the `to()`.

The problem is that Appium can't seem to find any of the properties in the content block for the page which is the current context when either the `onUnload()` or `onLoad()` methods are called. So long as the context is set to the approriate page, I can reference those properties in the test. Though when I try to find it in the Page file for that "page" during navigation, Appium is unable to find them. I've checked that the context is correct when either methods are called. Is there something I'm missing or could this be an issue with either Appium or Geb?

Currently testing against iOS -
Appium version: 1.5.3

Page file example:

```
class CurrentPage extends PreviousPage{   
@Override
void to(Map params, Objecct[] args){

    "actions which will cause the app to navigate to this page"

}

@Override
void onUnload(Page nextPage){
    thingIWantToClick.click() // Can't find this
}

public static content = {
    thingIWantToClick {"selector"} // Calling .click() on this in the test works

}
```

}

Comment: Maybe a minimal code sample ? :)

Comment: What do you mean by saying "can't seem to find any of the properties in the content block for the page which is the current context when either the onUnload() or onLoad() methods are called"? Do you see an exception? what exactly is it? Can you also provide the stacktrace please?